# Trouble running code in Visual Studio Code while using my MacBook

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code

As I try to use the hollow green triangle, it just sends me this text,

```
>>> /usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/vcvvvfcg/Documents/cc1/lab4/ejercicio1.gyp
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    /usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/vcvvvfcg/Documents/cc1/lab4/ejercicio1.gyp
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Though when I use the same button on my Mac's touch bar, it runs well. Any other way of making it work without using the touch bar?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you launched the REPL in the terminal that you originally used to launch files (note the `>>>`). If you exit the REPL -- you can run `exit()` to do that -- then the terminal will be back at the shell and execution will work again.